# How to use aspnet-codegenerator tool for scaffolding in vscode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm building an asp.net application using VScode, scaffolding areas using "aspnet-codegenerator" command always fail because of missing files.
[image]

I tried to uninstall the tool and reinstall it again, but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please try to check if `MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml` file does exist under that folder mentioned in error.

*Templates file path on my computer*

`C:\Users\user_name_here\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\verison_here(such as 3.1.4)\Templates\ControllerGenerator`

Besides, if you indeed installed [the `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-5.0#uninstall-aspnet-codegenerator), but error still occurs, you can try this workaround:

1. copy `Templates/ControllerGenerator` and `Templetes/ViewGenerator` to the project folder

   [image]
2. then rebuild the project and run your `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` command to generate controller and view etc.